# nearest City block distance between a point and line

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I want to find the point on a line segment drawn in an image which is at smallest city block distance from a given point.

Obvious method is to get the pixels on the line segment and for each pixel calculate the distance to get the minimum.
But can we do better than this ?

Comment: [*`City block distance`* is equal to *`Manhattan distance`* here](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/hc/hc_city_block_distance.htm). And then this question is the same to [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704257/nearest-manhattan-distance-between-a-point-and-line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point that is perpendicular to the line when connecting with the given point is a good guess. You can start from this point and then go both ends. You can stop if the distances increase on both directions. The solution is the stopping point.